# How to quickly enable/disable flash player support like FF web developer toolbar does for Javascript?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, flash

How to quickly enable/disable Flash player support like FF web developer toolbar does for Javascript?

Is there any solution for IE and Firefox both?

Answer (score 1):

For FF atleast [Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433) or [Flash Killer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5842)

Comment: The JavaScript/Greasemonkey version of another FlashBlock by Alexey Ruzanov (http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/46673) probably also works in IE, if one can somehow insert that into all received HTML. Like maybe by using "Greasemonkey for IE" -- http://www.gm4ie.com/

Answer (score 0):

A solution to IE and Firefox together would be some proxy server like [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/).

There, set a rule to block all `.swf` files.

When blocking content, `privoxy` gives a link instead of the blocked content to temporarily unblock it.

```
{+block{Flash Content.} +handle-as-image} 
# Block and replace with image
 .*\.swf
```